# How to call WSDL from Joomla view?

Tags: web-services, soap, joomla, wsdl, nusoap

Hi want to call web service from Joomla view. Joomla view.html.php has this code?

```
function albums(){
    require 'nusoap/lib/nusoap.php';

    $server = new nusoap_server();
    $server->configureWSDL("demo", "urn:demo");
    $server->register(
            'price', array('name' => 'xsd:string'), array('return' => 'xsd:string')
    );
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

}  



function price(){
    return "abcd";
}
```

when I load view on web page it shows to create get WSDL url but it is wrong?

> url page: 
>   http://localhost/admin/index.php/?option=com_news&view=gallery&layout=albums

**normally WSDL url is current url....?WSDL, but not working for joomla, then i tried it current url.....&WSDL it also not working... how to generate this**

**I tried to call this...but not working, can someone please help me.. thank you**

```
   require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
   $client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/admin/index.php/?option=com_news&view=gallery&layout=albums&WSDL");
   $result = $client->call(
        'price', 
        array(
            'name' => 'john'
        )
   );
   echo $result;
```

Comment: You should probably be using JHttp rather than rolling your own.  It's easy to use and handles a lot of this for you.   This "when I load view on web page it shows to create get WSDL url but it is wrong?" is really unclear what you mean (at least to me).   You can take a look at com_newsfeeds and JFeed to see a simple application (or look at JGoogle or JMediawiki).